# How can ik overrule the system size font in app

Tags: swiftui

In the iphone menu settings i can set my text size bigger.
Is it possible to overrule this in swiftui and set the size for example smaller ?

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `font` environment variable to change the default font within your app.

Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ChildView()
            .environment(\.font, .largeTitle)
    }
}


struct ChildView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello")

            Text("world!").font(.body) // Normal again
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]